# Mapping two string lists (in a short way) in Lisp?

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, hashtable

Lisp beginner here.

I have two string lists in this form with same length:

```
  keys = ("abc" "def" "gh" ...)
  values = ("qwe" "opr" "kmn" ...)
```

I need to construct hash-table or association lists (whichever is easy to construct and fast to get values from) from those lists. They are in the proper index due to their pair.

I know I can map them with iterating. But I want go with a more declarative way and I am looking for a clean way to this, if it can be done so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a dedicated function named [`PAIRLIS`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_pairli.htm) that does exactly what what you want to build association lists:

```
USER> (pairlis '("abc" "def" "gh")
               '("qwe" "opr" "kmn"))
(("gh" . "kmn") ("def" . "opr") ("abc" . "qwe"))
```

Note that the order is reversed, but this depends on the implementation. Here orders does not matter since your keys are unique.

Then, you can use the popular [alexandria](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/alexandria/alexandria) library to build a hash-table from that:

```
USER> (alexandria:alist-hash-table * :test #'equalp)
#<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUALP :COUNT 3 {101C66ECA3}>
```

Here I am using a hash-table with test `equalp` because your keys are strings.

NB. The [`*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v__stst_.htm) symbol refers to the last primary value in a REPL

Comment: Tx!, a quick question: I know I can get values in O(n) complexity from hash-table, but what about assoc list?

Comment: @drh0use the alist is a singly-linked list, so you need linear time to retrieve a value based on a key. The advantage of an alist is that it is functional and you can shadow values just by putting fresh cons cells in front of an existing list: if you call `(assoc :a '((:a . 0) (:b . 1) (:a -1)))`  you will get the first match for `:a` (the one which has a 0 value). See also [`acons`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_acons.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something such as mapcar which will handle the iteration for you, vs. manually entering some sort of loop for iteration. For example:

```
(defvar *first-names* '("tom" "aaron" "drew"))
(defvar *last-names* '("brady" "rogers" "brees"))
(defvar *names-table* (make-hash-table))
```

We could create a list of the two sets of names and then a hashtable (or alist if you prefer). Then we can simply user mapcar to map through the list of us instead of manually entering a loop such as do, dolist,  dotimes, loop ect…

```
(mapcar #'(lambda (first last)
           (setf (gethash first *names-table*) last))
       *first-names*
       *last-names*)
```

mapping is particularly useful for lists in common lisp.

Answer (score 1):

Note that as well as `pairlis` &c the normal mapping functions such as `mapcar` in fact take multiple list arguments and call the function being mapped on each of them.  So a simple-minded version of (part of) what `pairlis` does might be:

```
(defun kv->alist (keys values)
  (mapcar #'cons keys values))
```

(In fact this has an advantage over `pairlis` in some cases: the order of the result is determinate.)

And if you want to make a hashtable:

```
(defun kv->ht (keys values &key (test #'eql))
  (let ((ht (make-hash-table :test test)))
    (mapc (lambda (k v)
            (setf (gethash k ht) v))
          keys values)
    ht))
```